# .NET IExtenderProvider (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, iextenderprovider

I'm trying to extend the `TextBox`, `ComboBox` and `Panel` controls using `IExtenderProvider` but I cannot get it to work properly. I'm starting to believe that I haven't understood the concept completely.

Does anybody know any good resources on the web (with examples) on how `IExtenderProvider` is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/aspnet/FixingIExtenderProvider.asp
http://www.codeproject.com/aspnet/ExtenderProviderComponent.asp