# What is a good way to identify controls to set permissions?

Tags: c#, winforms, architecture, permissions

I need to implement permissions. It must be possible to make controls and forms (in)visibele based on the permissions of a user.

So, I need a way to identify the controls to set the permissions for. The application is kind of large and still growing. So, the way I apply permissions must be flexible.

I've thought about giving the controls a full name, like: namespace.formName.nameOfControl. But I don't like this because it is to fragile. When the name(space) changes, I need to change the identity as well, I don't want this, the chance coworkers and I forget to update this is to big.

So my question is, what do you think is a good way to identify the controls? There is a back office for an administrator to set the permissions

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomment that all aviable controls must implement a defined interface like "IAccessControled" there you can define a "PermissionKey"

As this name belongs to the interface it is independend of other properties the controls have (e.g. explicit interface implementation)

then you can scan through all IAccessControled Controles

Comment: Like the idea, but this means that I need to wrap every control class I want to set permissions on. So if I need to set a permission of a button control, I need to wrap the Button class.

Comment: You need your own class derived f rom buttm, right. But that seems ok for me. Because how else would you defined what is allowed to get permissions? And how they should be evaluated ? So having a permission or not endsup in some businesslogic which may vary depending on the control. in the easiest case you only have to implement the getter of a property which returns a string.

Comment: That is kind of my question :) I find it hard to determine how to identify a control.

Comment: That's why I think you need some kind of a marker ,which is not part of the bas class :-) You could also use attributes, but without an aop framework they can just mark, where Interfaces give you the chance to also in clude some methods like "RefreshPermissionState" or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Boas Enkler's answer is a good way to set permissions to things like Command or User Created class. However as you mentionned, it would require Wrapping every base controls to manage their permissions.

The approach I would recommend is to create a Custom Control that implements the `IExtenderProvider`. The `IExtenderProvider` simply lets you add Custom `Propreties` to the controls on the Form. So you could add a "PermissionRequired" propreties and you could set it while designing your WinForm.

I haven't been able to find some Tutorial that really pleases me, but those are best one I've found yet: [.NET IExtenderProvider (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182748/net-iextenderprovider-c/182761#182761)